# can i get it with css3 & html5? (gradient background, border gradient, transparency)

Tags: html, gradient, opacity, css

here is design of my button (different backgrounds for example, zoom ~1500% and actual size). how can i do it with single element and some css3, or minimum of additional elements? css guru, anyone?

http://ompldr.org/vZjBudQ/button.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="button"></a>​
```

CSS

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f5f0ee, #e7ddd7);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f5f0ee, #e7ddd7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f5f0ee, #e7ddd7);
    background: linear-gradient(#f5f0ee, #e7ddd7);
    border: 1px solid #c0b9b3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px #fcfbfb, 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.button:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -4px;
    top: -4px;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    background: linear-gradient(#f5f0ee, #e7ddd7);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZp8d/).

I think the only thing I couldn't get was the border with gradient.

Comment: thanks a lot, its cool! i think i can use :before/:after to emulate inner span and modernizr fallback with real span for older browsers, duh?

Comment: Yeah, I hate the additional tag myself, but I couldn't get rid of it. I'm gonna keep trying.

Comment: Derp. I was being lazy. I think you'll like the code much better now. :)

Comment: @user1581655 - If my answer provided a solution to your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark next to it. Doing so lets other people know you're getting value from the community. And you get +2 reputation added to you!